# Does Resharper provide additional XML Doc functionality to Visual Studio for C# class/method/property?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, xml-documentation

I found answer to
[Can I generate class and method summaries with ReSharper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725866/can-i-generate-class-and-method-summaries-with-resharper)

that says:

*If you have set your project to generate XML documentation, R# will offer the option to generate XML comments for public members*

I can't find any documentation about setting project to generate XML documentation OR Resharper to generate XML Doc comments. Only two RESHARPER->Edit->Comment with xxxx options.

Typing /// in Visual studio provides comment with summary tags but no text like

Gets or sets...

In addition I haven't found any functionality to generate XML Doc comments to all properties and methods of class.

Comment: GhostDoc is very useful and has a free version. Not affiliated with them, just a happy user. I use R# as well but never knew it to do xml doc. I know they have an extension that can inspect/validate  your xml doc though

Comment: thanks. i've read about GhostDoc and it seems that's what I have to get. i was just wondering if R# can do similar things.